# Registering web component to a task manager

Tags: notifications, polymer, local-storage, web-component, mediator

I am creating a few custom elements in polymer to handle notifications, local storage and an input element. I would like my input element decoupled from the storage element and the notification element. What I am doing is bubbling an event from the input element and handling in parent of input element and storage element where I wire it up to a registration function in the storage element, passed in the event detail is a reference to an object in my input element that provides a callback, a handle name, and a member that the storage element assigns a reference to its API on. The purpose of this is to allow me to switch out the storage element just by changing the wire up in the event handler that allows any element or object to register. Once there is two way communication with the storage interface, I start registering data formatted to have unique ID, the name of the handler used to register it, data object, action the registrant should take on this data at web page reload or when a user clicks a notification tied to this storage item. Once all handlers are registered after refresh or reload the data objects are passed to the callback in the related registered handler, the actions are completed and verified, the object is then removed from storage. The storage element will populate a notification element by bubbling an event and wiring it up in parent.

Is there a better way to make these custom elements portable allowing them to interact with the storage object without hard coding the name of the storage object? I would like to enable hot swap of storage controllers inside my registration allowing multiple different controllers to be used, one controller may be busy or other specifics may require the controller to be swapped out.

Comment: you could dynamically define the name of the storage object as an attribute of the custom element(s), no?

Comment: Some associations to this: Declarative dependency injection for Polymer elements https://firmfirm.github.io/f-di/

Comment: Dynamically changing the attribute would cause the custom element to complete some setup work from the property observer again. Instead I should bind the attribute to a single property on a custom element that provides hook for both the element that consumes the storage service, hook for the elements or service objects that will be load-balanced, and hook for controller to monitor services. Better to accomplish this with message passing and leave the implementation details outside of the element using the storage.